# Why does my screen appear plain black when I set up the root vc in the app delegate, when I have ui set up (storyboard)?

Tags: swift

When I set "HomePageVC" as my root view controller in the app delegate, it simply appears black (save the nav controller). "HomePageVC"'s UI elements have been set up via storyboard and not programmatically. I have made sure to sub class the ViewController in the canvas correctly, and the storyboard/restoration ID is the same as the sub class, ie "HomePageVC"

My app delegate-

```
let firstViewController = HomePageVC()
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: firstViewController)

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.rootViewController = navController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
```

My HomePageVC

For some reason, any programmatic UI that I use indeed does show up on the screen, but not any UI that I put in using the storyboard.

Comment: If `HomePageVC` is in a storyboard, why are you creating it and the window via code?

Comment: Its a project app, I'm learning how to set a vc as the root vc when the user is logged in, and the log in page as the root vc when the user is logged out.

Comment: if so then it's ok to write that inside AppDelegate just have an if-else statement with a boolean stored in userdefaults and set the root vc accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the vc is inside storboard you need to load it from there , so Replace

```
let firstViewController = HomePageVC()
```

with

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeId") as! HomePageVC
```

---

BTW you can embed the root vc inside a navigation in IB and set it as initial vc instead of this

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to app building; you were talking about the 
    window?.rootViewController = navController
line, correct? If yes, I see your point, thanks

Comment: if you use storyboard you can do all of this inside it from Editor menu select Embed then navigation you don't have to write anything inside appDelegate

Answer (score -1):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
    [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
{
    let mainStoryboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let initialViewController : UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomePageVC") as HomePageVC
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```